# Giving different Post page for same type based on category or Custom Taxonomy

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields, posts

I'm having a site which has option to add hotels and restaurants. Both for them has different custom fields which i have added meta boxes with a plugin. But the custom fields of hotel are not needed for restuarant and vice versa.

So what I want to achieve is create extra menu on admin panel saying Add Restaurant & Add Hotel. When clicked on Hotel its should only show the custom fields configured for Hotel. I know this can be achieved by custom post types. But i don't want another post type unless i have no options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out that this is not the right place to ask.
Better try codex.

Comment: why don't you try asking on [WordPress Answers](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/).  Stack Overflow's new beta WordPress Question and Answer site.